# Converting String to Date

Tags: java, parsing, date

How can I parse the following String "1394133302" which correspond of `Date.toString` value to a Date value (java utils).

Is it possible with a `SimpleDateFormat`?

Comment: what should be the o/p date for _1394133302_? is it a long date value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SimpleDateFormat` is used for formatting `Date` value, in your case you already have a long date value in terms of `String`convert it to `Long` and pass it directly to Date constructor to get date Object

```
Date dt = new Date(Long.valueOf("1394133302"));
```

Comment: This answer is likely **incorrect**. That `dt` object has a value of mid-January 1970, just 2-3 weeks after the Unix epoch. More likely to be correct is the [answer by Safrain](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22283064/642706).

Comment: @BasilBourque isn't this method correct for conversion? Not sure about the long value and the output date.

Comment: @BasilBourque Yes it seems we need to multiply this value with 1000 in this case as when I multiplied `1394133302` with 1000 I got `Thu Mar 06 13:15:02 CST 2014`.

Answer (score 4):

Use code below

```
    new Date(Long.valueOf("1394133302"))
```

PS. It seems you date string is in second, maybe you want this(convert it to millesecond!)

```
    new Date(Long.valueOf("1394133302") * 1000L)
```

Comment: Isn't there a problem with the specific time-zone to take care of?
I use JodaTime for that.
http://www.joda.org/joda-time/

Comment: From the [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) : "Allocates a Date object and initializes it to represent the specified number of milliseconds since the standard base time known as "the epoch", namely January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT."  it is in GMT,Date.getTime() is also in GMT

Answer (score 3):

Just feed it back into the Date constructor:

```
long dateAsLong = Long.parseLong( "1394133302");
Date someDate = new Date(dateAsLong);
```